# Creating Custom Functionality To The CampusLife App

Tags: desire2learn

Our institution currently has Campus Life deployed for our students to use. Since the release, we have been receiving feedback from students requesting that we have more tools integrated into the app. I have been reviewing your documentation on creating custom Campus Life Modules (http://code.google.com/p/desire2learn-valence/wiki/MobileSDK) and was wondering if it’s possible to create modules that link into the Learning Environment’s tools the same way grades, news, classlist ect. currently do in the app. An example of something we’d like to have implemented is students to have the ability to save content from their courses onto their mobile device through the app.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create modules for CampusLife that integrate with the Learning Environment. The MobileSDK that you have linked above is your starting point for writing an application that can run as a CampusLife module. For integration with the Learning Environment, here is a documentation starting-point:

http://desire2learn.com/r/ValenceHome

For course content, you are going to be most interested in routes here:
http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/content.html

particularly these:

http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/content.html#get--d2l-api-le-(D2LVERSION-version)-(D2LID-orgUnitId)-content-toc

http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/content.html#get--d2l-api-le-(D2LVERSION-version)-(D2LID-orgUnitId)-content-modules-(D2LID-moduleId)-structure-

http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/content.html#get--d2l-api-le-(D2LVERSION-version)-(D2LID-orgUnitId)-content-topics-(D2LID-topicId)

Comment: Thanks Mike for your answer. Looking at the android example, does it already have the needed library included to make these valence calls?

Comment: It doesn't, but you can download the library for making those calls here: http://code.google.com/p/desire2learn-valence/downloads/list?q=label:droidlatestclient. If you want, I believe the pure Java implementation needs only a minor tweak to get working, surrounding Base64 encoding, it's located here: https://code.google.com/p/desire2learn-valence/downloads/list?q=label:javalatestclient

Comment: Because the code repository used to house the client library packages might change at some point, it might be better to provide this URL, the homepage in the Valence platform docs for all the client libraries (http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/clients/index.html).